# non-dev user always has ID 0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have ran into a serious problem that must be resolved before continuing with the development.

My boss created the app, for him it works exactly as expected - the user is logged in, the data is accessible, everything works. BUT for every other user, $facebook->getUser() ALWAYS returns 0, no matter what. Obviously, I'm logged into facebook, there is also a login link in the app, but clicking it doesn't work, nothing changes.

*This problem only occurs for users that are not in any way connected to the app!*

I confirmed my developer request to that app a few days ago and it now works for my account, before that it did not work, not for me, not for any other user we tried, no matter if the app was public or in dev mode, which technically shouldn't matter for authentication.

We tried many things, eventually existing code shared on the internet, like the code from the bottom of this article: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/develop-facebook-app/
(with our own app ID and secret, of course)
Not that it changed anything, but just to give you a ready code example.

Even if I deleted everything below "$user = $facebook->getUser();" and just put `echo $user; die();` after that, it always showed the user ID as 0.

Another thing I've noticed that might help in solving this problem is the following: with the same code from the article, my boss' session contains several variables at all times, but when I open the app with a non-dev user, at first there is only the "fb_app-id_state" variable, and when I refresh the page, it gets deleted and session is empty. If I refresh the page again, the variable is created again with a different value, another refresh and it's gone again, and so on.

After a day of trying to get this shit to work with PHP, I switched to the JS SDK. Apparently it also doesn't work, however, I have yet to receive specifics from my boss since I don't have a fake account to test it myself.

The obvious question is: what is going on and why isn't the authentication working as expected?

Edit: my code - http://pastebin.com/qCPtfTHs

Comment: Can you post your code? and is `baseurl` in Facebook configuration as same as Website URL in App dashboard? they must be the same

Comment: @AdamAzad added link to code. The app is a Page Tab app, there is only a Page Tab URL, and the app has only one page. I have no idea where to put that `baseurl` you mentioned. Is it really required in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You need looking for app settings. Only owner, app admin, dev, can use your aplication on sandbox mode. All other users this app dont work or work buggy. Remove test mode, and put out app in live mode.

Comment: "no matter if the app was public or in dev mode".